# Flutter SharedPreferences.getInt('key') returning "Instance of Future<dynamic>"

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, variable-assignment, return-type

I'm trying to assign the result of an `getInt('key')` to an int variable with a function, but it returns "Instance of Future". I don't know how to get the value out of this... Here is the following code:

```
getMainColorInt() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    
  final int? mainColorInt = prefs.getInt("mainColorInt");
    
  return prefs.getInt("mainColorInt");
}

class Palette {
static int colorInt = getMainColorInt();
}
```

When I try to print(getMainColorInt()) it returns "Instance of Future< dynamic >"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, you just have to do this:

```
Palette.colorInt = prefs.getInt("mainColorInt");
```

Answer (score 1):

```dart
static int colorInt = await getMainColorInt();
```

because the funtion is `async`:

`getMainColorInt() async {`